# Audio player gets auto disposed

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

The audio player gets disposed when changing audio files. The app plays sequential audio in files in the shared\audio folder. The first file plays ok but stops after first audio. Im using Plugin.SimpleAudioplayer
Here's the code, what am i doing wrong.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private ISimpleAudioPlayer audio;
    private int pagenum;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void playaudio(int pgnum)
    {
        audio = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
        audio.PlaybackEnded += cmdNextClicked; 
        
        var stream = GetStreamFromFile(string.Concat("audio.w", (pgnum + 1).ToString(), ".mp3"));
        audio.Load(stream);
        audio.Play();
    }

    Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("App1." + filename);
        return stream;
    }

    private void cmdRunClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)//
    {
        playaudio(pagenum);
    }

    private void cmdStopClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)//
    {
       if (!(audio is null))
        {
            audio.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void cmdClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        audio.Seek(audio.CurrentPosition + 30.0);
    }

    private void cmdNextClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        pagenum++;
        lblPageNo.Text = pagenum.ToString();
        playaudio(pagenum);
    }

    private void cmdPrevClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pagenum--;
        lblPageNo.Text = pagenum.ToString();
        playaudio(pagenum);
    }
}
```

Comment: "but stops after first audio" - do you get an error or exception?  Why do you think it is being disposed?

Comment: coz it shows a message:System.ObjectDisposedException: 'the player object was Dispose()d during the callback, this has corrupted the state of the program
Object name: 'player'.'

Comment: ![Unhandled exception ](https://ibb.co/64BJ445)

Comment: As a test, comment out `audio.PlaybackEnded += cmdNextClicked;`. Then after first one ends, manually click Next button to play next audio. Same problem?

Comment: audio.PlaybackEnded += cmdNextClicked; 
this looks more like code you'd want to initialize once, vs every playaudio call, you are attaching multiple event handlers to the PlayEnded on every call.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: Yes, it works after i comment it and manually click cmdNext.  Debug original code i found that it loads 2nd page and plays it, only when debbugger comes back to cmdNext code and exits it does the error occur.
1

Comment: @Christopher Richmond: even moving these 2 lines after ' InitializeComponent(); ' in 'mainpage()'  <br/>  audio = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
            audio.PlaybackEnded += cmdNextClicked;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the new symptom (crash happens after return from cmdNext), queue to run *after* PlaybackEnded handler returns:

```cs
// NOTE: As Christopher Richmond commented, move this to a place that is only called once.
audio.PlaybackEnded += SafePlayNext;
...

private void SafePlayNext(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Queue to run after return.
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        cmdNextClicked(null, null));   // Arguments not used, `null` works fine.
}
```

EXPLANATION: Starting another audio apparently *disposes* the previous audio. Original code started another audio, then handler ends, and returns to that audio's PlaybackEnded event processor. Something is accessed on that disposed audio. Thus the disposed Exception.

The above code puts the `cmdNextClicked` call on to MainThread's queue, then immediately returns to that audio's PlaybackEnded. Which thus has a chance to finish, before the next audio is asked for.